# CSS3: Smooth transition between animations change on :hover

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an elements that has infinite css3 animation that is changed to another infinite animation when element is hovered. Everything is ok, but sometimes animation changing is too bouncy, is there a way to make transition between animations smooth (maybe bringing element to the initial state between animations) on mouseenter and mouseleave? The starting and ending states of both animations are the same.

```
@keyframes first-animation {
0% { transform: scale3d(1,1,0);}
50% { transform: scale3d(0.8,0.8,0); }
100% { transform: scale3d(1,1,0); }
};

@keyframes second-animation {
0% { transform: scale3d(1,1,0); }
70% { transform: scale3d(0.7,0.7,0); }
80% { transform: scale3d(0.9,0.9,0); }
100% { transform: scale3d(1,1,0);  }
};

div{
animation: first-animation 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
}

div:hover, div:focus{
animation: second-animation 1.1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a pure CSS solution? If so the answer is no. If not then you can wait for an `onAnimationEnd` event to switch it

Comment: For a more precise animation, I'd step out of `'ease-in-out'` and give it a try to `cubic-beizer()` http://cubic-bezier.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that it can be achieved using the scale transforms.

You can do a trick and change from scale() to translateZ(). When a perspective is applied, the net effect will be also a scale. But the interesting point is than setting perspective to a high value, this scale effect can be made very small. And perspective is an animatable property.

The downside is that we will need to add 2 wrap around layers... but the final result is this. I have kept the original version to compare

```css
@keyframes first-animation {
0% { transform: scale(1,1);}
50% { transform: scale(0.8,0.8); }
100% { transform: scale(1,1); }
}

@keyframes second-animation {
0% { transform: scale(1,1); }
70% { transform: scale(0.7,0.7); }
80% { transform: scale(0.9,0.9); }
100% { transform: scale(1,1);  }
}

.sample {
    background-color: lightblue;
    animation: first-animation 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.sample:hover {
animation: second-animation 1.1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.dim {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.base1 {
    perspective: 1000px;
    transition: perspective 2s ease-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: 300px;
  top: 10px;
}
.base1:hover {
    perspective: 9999px;
}

.base2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: animation1 1.7s ease-in-out infinite;
    perspective: 9999px;
    transition: perspective 2s ease-in;
}
.base1:hover .base2 {
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    animation: animation2 1.1s ease-in-out infinite;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 99999px;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
0% { transform: translateZ(0px);}
50% { transform: translateZ(-200px); }
100% { transform: translateZ(0px); }
}

@keyframes animation2 {
      0% { transform: translateZ(0px);}
     70% { transform: translateZ(-300px); }
     80% { transform: translateZ(-100px); }
    100% { transform: translateZ(0px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="sample dim">SAMPLE</div>
<div class="base1 dim">
    <div class="base2">
        <div class="inner">DEMO</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the desired effect then you will need to use the css3 animation events. in this case you need to use "AnimationIteration". So you can fire an event after an iteration. I have added a class to the end of this event for the second animation.

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/c63c21ad652e469bc4a02b5f260db90c)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var animationElement = $(".animation");

  $("body").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      animationElement.one('webkitAnimationIteration mozAnimationIteration AnimationIteration', function() {
        animationElement.addClass("second-animation");
      });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      animationElement.one('webkitAnimationIteration mozAnimationIteration AnimationIteration', function() {
        animationElement.removeClass("second-animation");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you used the **transition**?? If not, please add the transition rules in the parent div.

```
div{
-webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 500ms linear;
-o-transition: all 500ms linear;
transition: all 500ms linear;
}
```